# Multiple rollover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created multiple image rollovers using Dreamweaver but was told in a previous Stackoverflow post that the javascript code Dreamweaver uses is out of date. So, I googled and read up on the correct way to use image rollover menus.

However, now it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

The HTML -

```
<div id="nav">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="thurs"><a href="#">Thurs</a></li>
<li class="fri"><a href="#">Fri</a></li>
<li class="sat"><a href="#">Sat</a></li>
<li class="sun"><a href="#">Sun</a></li>
<li class="more"><a href="#">More</a></li>
```

And the CSS -

```
.thurs      { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png);     }
.thurs a        { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/K8umxhswx/thu.png);       }

.fri            { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/dCtmxht0o/fri-hover.png);         }
.fri a          {background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/9dtmxhsw1/fri.png);        }

.sat            { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/qfsmxhstx/sat-hover.png);         }
.sat a          {background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/drJmxhstf/sat.png);        }

.sun            {  background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Vy4mxhssp/sun-hover.png);        }
.sun a      { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Uekmxhss1/sun.png);       }

.more       { background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Bjzmxhsvf/more-hover.png);        }
.more a     {background-image: url (http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/i8jmxhsuu/more.png);       }
```

I also made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m772P/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this

```
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width:250px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
}
.thurs a       { background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/K8umxhswx/thu.png');       }
.thurs a:hover { background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');     }


.fri a       {background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/9dtmxhsw1/fri.png');      }
.fri a:hover { background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/dCtmxht0o/fri-hover.png');       }

.sat a       {background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/drJmxhstf/sat.png');      }
.sat a:hover { background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/qfsmxhstx/sat-hover.png');       }

.sun a       { background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Uekmxhss1/sun.png');         }
.sun a:hover {  background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Vy4mxhssp/sun-hover.png');      }

.menu li.more a {height: 150px;}
.more a      {background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/i8jmxhsuu/more.png');         }
.more a:hover{ background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/Bjzmxhsvf/more-hover.png');      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m772P/13/

but the better way to do this is cache images and change `background-position` on hover

Comment: Perhaps scope the `li a` to `.menu li a` so that it doesn't change other parts of the page as well.

Comment: Thank you @arclite, this works great, but when I add li {     display: inline-block; } li a {     vertical-align:top; } (I want the menu to sit at the top of the site), it all goes a bit loopy

Comment: first of all you should use `.menu li {display: inline-block}` you should add some display to `ul.menu` and editted code in my answer

Comment: :-/ http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/2u9mxkgdd/screen_shot_2013-12-10_at_01.05.45.png

Comment: in jsfiddle it works fine i think you have error in other part of your script

Comment: I've checked my code and can't see anything interfering with the menu http://basement001.tumblr.com/

Comment: add `float:left;` to `.menu li`

Comment: The menu is still repeating... unsure why

Comment: cause you have two anchors in `<li class="thurs">` remove one and it'll be all right

Comment: I dont... it shows when you view source, but it's not there in my actual stylesheet. As an experiment I deleted the whole of Thurs, and then Fri began repeating twice

Answer (score 0):

You need display: block; or inline-block on the anchor :) Also, you need options for "repeat" and "position" -- right now you're just specifying the image itself.

css:

```
li a {
   display: block;
   padding-left: 20px; /* if you want the image to appear to the left of the text, adjust      the width according to the image size*/
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between url and the open parentheses.

```
.thurs {
  background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png);
}
```

It may be that ".thurs a" chould be ".thurs:hover", but I'm not clear on the details of how you are using it.

Comment: Thank you, @Jason Aller. I had no idea space could disturb the code

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you need the :hover css selector, and your background isn't displaying because you have a space between "url (".

Try something like this with those points fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/m772P/4/

```
.thurs a        { background-image: url();      }
.thurs a:hover      { background-image: url();      }
```